# Clearing all FTP sessions

Tags: ftp, connections

I am receiving this error:

[image]

I've closed down all of my FTP Clients (I use Panic Transmit + Coda on my Macbook & Filezilla on my other laptop). And I've locked my FTP and unlocked it again from within the control panel.

How do I end the session for all users currently connected via FTP to my server? (I'm thinking through Terminal?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can close connection on your server using some commands:

1. netstat + kill

   ```
   netstat -na
   kill PID
   ```
2. tcpkill

   ```
   tcpkill -i eth0 host 10.0.0.1
   ```
3. killcx (http://spamcleaner.org/en/misc/killcx.html)

   ```
   killcx <ip>:<port>
   ```
4. tcpdrop command (FreeBSD):

   ```
   tcpdrop myhost.net:2353 example.com:ftp
   ```